# Is there a way to find the ID of the LAST element within a DIV using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, find, append, html-lists

I think I need to find the id of the last element in my div so that I can append a ul element after it using javascript. The reason for this is that the existing/last ul in my div is generated dynamically so its id could be anything.

I have tried simply appending the element to the div container using the following code, expecting it to put it at the end..

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var newUL = document.createElement("ul");
container.appendChild(newUL);
newUL.innerHTML = 'Hello';
```

But this for some reason appends the new ul outside of my div container. Does anyone know why this happens? but also how to find the last element's id so that I can append it after the last element? Thanks.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, `$('#container ul:last')` selects the last child.

Comment: Also, you might want to append the `container` object to the document before you append the `newUL` object.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. http://jsbin.com/izunur/ just works

Comment: @Pat the container is already in the html.

Comment: @Gerben i see your point although I have a lot of <ul></ul> elements already appended to the div..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
container.lastElementChild.id
```

But I think you need to find the real problem. An UL can't contain text. It may only contain li-elements.

Comment: Actually you are spot on, I just needed to add the <li></li> tags around the innerHTML.. Thanks.

Comment: `newUL.innerHTML = '<li>Hello</li>';`

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to rely on a Javascript framework such as **[jQuery](http://jquery.com/)** to tackle this problem.

jQuery allow you to answer your situation with this simple code:

```
$('#container').append(
  $('<ul></ul>').text('Hello')
);
```

**EDIT:** Took into account arnaud576875's comment.

Comment: I've never had a problem in IE using `$('<ul />')` but like @Gerben said, the real problem is that the UL shouldn't have a text node directly inside of it

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the innerHTML of a `ul` element to a simple string : `'Hello'`; that contravenes the rules. Perhaps a better test would be to add some `li` elements :

```
newUl.innerHTML = "<li>One</li><li>Two</li>";
```